# What is the minimal $ n $ such that the Cox ring of the blow up of a simplicial, $ r $-dimensional, toric variety at $ n $ points in g.p. is not f.g.?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, toric-varieties

In Shigeru Mukai's paper "Counterexample to Hilbert's 14th Problem for the 3-dimensional Additive Group," Mukai proved that if $ \frac{1}{r+1}+\frac{1}{n-r-1} \le \frac{1}{2} $, then the blow up of $ \mathbb{P}^{r} $ at $ n $ points in general position is not finitely generated.  Is there a lower bound on $ n $ so that if $ X_{\Sigma} $ is a $ r $-dimensional, projective, simplicial toric variety over a field of arbitrary characteristic, then the Cox ring of the blow up of $ X_{\Sigma} $ at $ n $ points in general position is not finitely generated?

@user347489 reminded me that I should clarify that I do not merely want a number $ n $ such that for some $ r $-dimensional toric variety $ X_{\Sigma} $ the blow-up of $ n $-points in general position has a non-finitely generated Cox ring, but an $ n(r) $ such that for all toric varieties $ X_{\Sigma} $ the Cox ring of the blow-up of $ X_{\Sigma} $ in $ n(r) $-points in general position is not finitely generated.  This question may be too broad or not have enough parameters.  If one specifies also that the class group of $ X_{\Sigma} $ is free of rank $ \ell $, does that add any information?

Answer (score 1):

There is an ongoing effort to understand this problem, since it's already very complicated for the simplest examples: weighted projective planes blown up at a single general point. Below I mostly discuss this case.

Historically, the first geometric study of the problem was done [by Cutkosky](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Symbolic-algebras-of-monomial-primes.-Cutkosky/26ee360d200c90bbce7f5d983def4f3ae25d1b05) in '91, motivated by an equivalent problem originating from commutative algebra. The first non-MDS examples were found in '94 by Goto, Nishida and Watanabe, and, as far as I know, the area became mostly inactive after this (with the exception of some works by Kurano and different collaborators, see below). Twenty years later Castravet and Tevelev's proof that $\overline{M}_{0,n}$ is not a MDS uses these blow-ups in an essential way. The question you ask has received renewed interest since then.

Gonzalez-Anaya, Gonzalez and Karu have a series of papers addressing this problem. See for example [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.03950), where they offer a summary of their previous work and exhibit some deeper structures underlying the problem. Their last preprint finds examples of projective toric surfaces with Picard number 1 with a semiopen effective cone, [see here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.13333).

Other papers addressing the problem include work of Kurano with several coauthors like Cutkosky, Matsuoka and Nishida (in his [latest paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.01889) with Inagawa they settle [a conjecture of He](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10586458.2018.1547232?journalCode=uexm20)), work of Laface and Ugaglia, etc.

It's worth mentioning that not too long ago [Castravet, Laface, Tevelev and Ugaglia](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.14298) showed that $\overline{M}_{0,n}$ has a non-polyhedral pseudoeffective cone for $n\geq 10$ by showing the same property for a toric surface with higher Picard number.

I can offer some more details if you wish.

Comment: I have looked at some of these papers.  I know that for some weighted projective surfaces or three folds it is possible to blow up one point to obtain a surface/three fold with non-finitely generated Cox ring.  I should clarify and state that while it may be possible to blow-up $ m<n(r) $ points in general position for some $ r $-dimensional toric varieties and obtain a non-finitely generated Cox ring, that I am curious about an $ n(r) $ such that for all $ r $-dimensional toric varieties if one blows up $ n(r) $-points the Cox ring is non-finitely generated.  I will edit the question.